# How to overcome Unique constraint error in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Suppose one of my session ran successful for last 10days and today it's getting failed because of unique conatarint error. How to resolve this issue with changing session properties

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest non-recommended approach and if you dont care about rejected data, set `stop on error =0` in the session like below pic- This will log the rejected rows into session log and let the session succeeded.
[image: stop on err]

But, ideally you should handle the error properly in mapping. Like use a lookup on the target to create a flag if record is to be inserted/updated. Then use an update strategy and use DD_UPDATE or DD_INSERT based on the flag to the target.

Comment: Please note this will still cause errors, log them and make the session run quite long. It will not fail the session, but the errors will still be there. Best option is to prevent those errors from happening by either using updates where needed, or skipping the already existing rows.